# Set default date to a Date Filter using Dataset in SSRS Report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am working on SSRS 2012, I have used a Date filter, Trying to Bind default value
that is based on a Dataset into that Date Filter Calendar,

I have also Converted the date in the Parameter EXpression as 
Exp= Format(Fields!FromDate.Value,"mm/DD/YYYY")

Date from the Dataset as eg. =21/08/2018

The date is getting bind into the Textbox, but not in the calendar
 [image: Image with the error]

Expected Output = The Default selected Date for the Calendar should be from the Query.

Comment: What is ValidValues?

Comment: "From" is the name of the Parameter, Nothing is like the "ValidValues" it might be the invalid value error

Comment: Actually I have done this before but I'm not getting how your report is designed

Comment: The Parameter Calendar is set to type 'Date'?

Comment: Yes, The Parameter Calendar is set to type 'Date/Time', Because there is no option for Date only.
When I do Set as Text, It's working, But want the same date into the Calendar.

Comment: Are you passing the data value from dataset by keeping in some Format?

Comment: Yes, The default Format is like "8/24/2018"  and Data is coming from query is
"08/24/2018"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177729/discussion-between-anand-maurya-and-semicolon).

Comment: I'm not sat near my reports at the moment, but I have a vague recollection of having to cast the date field and parameter as date format, (in the SQL query) 

Something along the lines of 
`where cast(rDate as date) = cast(@datep as date)`

Answer (score 0):

The Date that was coming from Query was varchar that should be in DateTime Data type,
This has solved the issue

Earlier it was as: 
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(Datetime, FromDate, 120),101) as 'FromDate' from @TempTable

Final query:  select  CONVERT(Datetime, FromDate, 120) as 'FromDate' from @TempTable

Thanks to all who responded to my question.